# Python: Parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="/watch?gl=US&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en&amp;v=0C_yXOhJxWg">Miss Black OCU 2011</a>
```

My program reads a html file, and above is the chunk of that file. I want to grab `Miss Black OCU 2011` using BeautifulSoup in python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the attributes of the Tag and NavigableString class

```
text = """<a href="/watch?gl=US&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en&amp;v=0C_yXOhJxWg">Miss Black OCU 2011</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
print soup.find('a').text
```

Answer (score 0):

If the href attribute follow a literal pattern like href = "...watch..."
You could easily solve the problem using re: regular expression.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = """<a href="/watch?gl=US&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en&amp;v=0C_yXOhJxWg">Miss Black OCU 2011</a>""" 
# the response should might be the urlreponse object if you search through a whole html page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
print soup.find("a", {"href":re.compile(".*watch.*")}).text
```

The output is like this:

```
Miss Black OCU 2011
```

The whole point is find the regular expression pattern. More info about re, click here http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html: